# Publisher GUID and ad control

Tags: windows-phone-7, guid

How I do to associate my publisher GUID to a ad control at my WP7 application?

Comment: [Guid] tag is not specific. If you want to get an answer from experts the platform/technology tag (e.g. [windows-phone-7] will be the best choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you associate your Application ID (GUID) with AdControl rather than Publisher Id (again GUID). Internally, Publisher Id and Application Ids should be related at MarketPlace (Store).
You can find more detailed information here at:
http://advertising.microsoft.com/mobile-apps and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288088.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: I found this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj206730(v=vs.105)  that explain how i solve my problem too, and with the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh288088.aspx  you give me  now I can do what I pretend. :) thanks